# Depending Generic ResultType in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, return-type

Hi everyone!

```js
interface Data {
  date: Date;
  message?: string;
}

interface DataB {
  dateB: Date;
  messageB?: string;
}

class DataResolver {
  public submit(): Data {
    return { date: new Date() };
  }

  public submitB(): DataB {
    return { dateB: new Date() };
  }
}

interface StringKeyedObject {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Handler<C extends StringKeyedObject> {
  send<
    K extends Extract<keyof C, string>,
    L extends ReturnType<Extract<keyof K, object>>,
  >(eventName: K, arg: L) {
    //
  }
}
const handler = new Handler<DataResolver>();
handler.send('submit', null);
```

I really would like to set the second `arg` parameter depending on the first `value` paramter. In VS Code autocomplete suggests `submit` and `submitB` as intended.  Now if I select `submit` I would like to be arg of type `Data`. If I select `submitB` the type should be `DataB`.

My attempt with generic type `L extends ReturnType<Extract<keyof K, object>>` does not work at all. Obviously.

I hope you'll find a solution! Thanks an all the best!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without errors or issues *unrelated* to your question.  It looks like `Data` and `DataB` should be *interfaces* and not classes (unless you are going to construct them with `new`, in which case you shouldn't be making them with object literals) and you have at least one typo in `submitB`.  This will make it so that people can easily work on your issue without being distracted by having to fix things that aren't your issue first.

Comment: Once you do that: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdvjdW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi. :) I edited the code above. `Data` and `DataB` have to be classes. Changing this in your approach seems to do the trick. Thanks for that!  But how? How does this work? Could you explain your solution?

Comment: They may “have to be classes” in your actual code, but in this example they don’t have to be classes, and having them as classes is distracting because: you’re not initializing required properties; and you’re returning object literals in methods that claim to return class instances, so `instanceof` won’t behave as expected. Unless you’re trying to ask about that stuff, please [edit] to make them interfaces for the purposes of this question.  Again if you want classes in your actual code that’s fine, but this question  should benefit future readers as well.

Comment: I can see that.  Will change for future benefits. Could you then explain the generic expression?

Comment: Yes, I will write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
class Handler<C extends StringKeyedObject> {
  send<K extends Extract<keyof C, string>>(
    value: K, arg: C[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Here the `arg` parameter type depends on `K`. It is essentially the same as `ReturnType<C[K]>`, so let's first look at that version first:

```
class Handler<C extends StringKeyedObject> {
  send<K extends Extract<keyof C, string>>(
    value: K, arg: ReturnType<C[K]> ) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

The type `C[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) meaning "the property type you'd read when indexing into an object of type `C` with a key of type `K`".  It is presumably what you were trying to do with `keyof K`, except that [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) on `K` would give you "the keys of the keys of C", which is like, whatever keys a string has... `toUppercase` and such.  Not what you wanted.

And note that, unless you have a special reason, you don't need to have a separate type parameter for `arg`.  You could have written `L extends ReturnType<C[K]>` and used `L`, but we don't need some arbitrary *subtype* of `ReturnType<C[K]>` for this to work, so there's no reason to add another type parameter.

---

So, given this definition, let's make sure it works:

```
class DataResolver {
  public submit(): Data { return { date: new Date() }; }
  public submitB(): DataB { return { dateB: new Date() }; }
  a = 2 // I added this
}
const handler = new Handler<DataResolver>();
handler.send("submit", { date: new Date() }); // okay
handler.send("submitB", { dateB: new Date() }); // okay
handler.send("a", "wha") // <-- shouldn't compile but it does
```

Everything works the way you want, except... if your `DataResolver` happens to have a non-function property, we don't want the compiler to accept any call to `handler.send()` for that property.  One way to do that is to check whether the property value is a function type, and if so, use its return type; and if not, use [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  That brings us back to:

```
class Handler<C extends StringKeyedObject> {
  send<K extends Extract<keyof C, string>>(
    value: K, arg: C[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

where `arg` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on `C[K]`.  [The use of `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) lets us extract out the return type as its own type parameter `R` and use it.

By the way, this is very similar to [how `ReturnType<T>` is defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/13c374a868c926f6a907666a5599992c1351b773/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1605):

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

except that this version gives [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) when `T` isn't a function, and since `any` accepts anything, the call to `handler.send("a", "wha")` succeeds when it shouldn't.

Okay, let's test it one more time:

```
const handler = new Handler<DataResolver>();
handler.send("submit", { date: new Date() }); // okay
handler.send("submitB", { dateB: new Date() }); // okay
handler.send("a", "wha") // error!
// -------------> ~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Looks good.  There are other ways to harden `send` against bad inputs (we could make it so that you're not even allowed to give it keys corresponding to non-functions) but I don't want to digress even further from the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AEwwgC40SBufZAWwgGcG4BzCAfnIbClBeoC+uXKEixEKdJgBCOGsUjTyUiNQL0mrCNM7JuvEP1xDcCADZwmFTACVGAezMA3aHIIAHAK4AjM8AR6PrTAYAAUAJTKGFjYyFAQYJ5QIDhEJOQgEADu1hARyAKUBTRevv6B3sFg0hFRMqnxicmpCtoZ2bn5hcUEWAC8yABMyAD0I8gAkshwhIQQhMhgABbADMbCotDwSMgAyjx8ANIQAJ7zAPLeAFYQCGBuyADaANanXAeGALrkcCAngsJzJYGMgABK-QhmaAAHgAwsgIAAPSAgQgg-YGFjHM6ES43O4APgeDAgqOhhwRyNJaOQAFFkVBEGBoa8TvYYMhYQAaPQfFgEgmhGgEJxwMyeMjIQ48uBQFjkWGPQ6fSkommhAB0WtlLAYPz+4WQfSJoBgrhsyHYyAt7RcUENeAIBDGRHsvM8MBgNCEQgQ9hA3GQSwhUKgRuQmRy4NRoehUjgdgYjjtgvC1GDMegGpJqNCACIGEEQnmebFWu0cioumnRuN7M84CdcBnIVmc4R84XKiFpCWWiQlBGOlXDQIay7643myG29T83A+3mssG84aXdAoPYoABCXAugC0h6Px6PRIAfheL3vxgBBOWeejgZDsxYndwoADk+j4H+Qqwj9j3MCwAsCAcC+CgYBuu4spwPQYjPhyYBvp+mR2h+GpAA)

Comment: This is great!  Thanks @jcalz for the solution and the answer! Thanks for your time to explain it in detail. This will help a lot!